# Nested select statement w/ multiple joins (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join, nested

I'm having issues transferring a query that works in SQL Server Management Studio to MS Access. I'm getting an error:

> Syntax error in JOIN operation

The line 'FROM ProductRun' is highlighted when I get this error.

I think Access requires brackets when dealing with multiple Join statement which I've done. I'm stuck. Please help.

```
SELECT 
    LoadTable.DateTimeStamp, ProgramTable.Value 1, PL.Value 2, PL.Value 3
FROM
    ((LoadTable 
LEFT JOIN 
    ProgramTable ON LoadTable.DateTimeStamp = ProgramTable.DateTimeStamp) 
LEFT JOIN 
    PL ON LoadTable.DateTimeStamp = PL.DateTimeStamp)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT [StartTime], [EndTime]
     FROM ProductRun
     WHERE ProductRun.StartTime >= '11/1/2017' 
       AND ProductRun.Startime <= '12/1/2017') ON (LoadTable.DateTimeStamp >= DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, ProductRun.StartTime) 
                                               AND LoadTable.DateTimeStamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, ProductRun.EndTime))
ORDER BY 
    LoadTable.DateTimeStamp;
```

This is my nested select statement in Management Studio which works just fine:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [StartTime] 
      ,[EndTime]
FROM [ProductionReporting].[dbo].ProductRun
 WHERE StartTime between '11/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' and '11/25/2017 12:00:00 AM') as M3
 ON M1.DateTimeStamp between DATEADD(MINUTE,15, M3.StartTime) and DATEADD(MINUTE,-15, M3.EndTime)
```

Comment: I don't think MS Access allows inequalities in the `ON` clause.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the nested query in Management studio which works fine. How would I go about in making this work in Access if logic tests are not allowed in ON clauses?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Access does allow them (I've used them in multiple queries). I think Kashif correctly spotted the error, the first argument of `DateAdd` should be a string, `MINUTE` is not a valid argument (Access probably thinks that's a parameter in a place where there shouldn't be one). Also, multiple comparisons in an `ON` clause = parentheses required in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT loadtable.datetimestamp, 
       programtable.value AS 1, 
       pl.value           AS 2, 
       pl.value           AS 3 
FROM   ((loadtable 
         LEFT JOIN programtable 
                ON loadtable.datetimestamp = programtable.datetimestamp) 
        LEFT JOIN pl 
               ON loadtable.datetimestamp = pl.datetimestamp) 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT starttime, 
                         endtime 
                  FROM   productrun 
                  WHERE  productrun.starttime >=#11/1/2017# 
                         AND productrun.starttime <=#12/1/2017# ) a 
              ON loadtable.datetimestamp >= Dateadd("n", 15, a.starttime) 
                 AND loadtable.datetimestamp <= Dateadd("n", -15, a.endtime) 
ORDER  BY loadtable.datetimestamp;
```

Comment: This answer is nearly correct, Access does require a set of parentheses when doing multiple comparisons in an `ON` clause: `ON (loadtable.datetimestamp >= Dateadd("n", 15, a.starttime) 
                 AND loadtable.datetimestamp <= Dateadd("n", -15, a.endtime))`